# Matching parenthesis and such not being highlighted in strings since VIM 8.0 on Ubuntu 18.04, how do I get this highlighting back?

Tags: highlight, vim8, plugin-matchit

When I place the cursor on the parenthesis of the below line, the two parenthesis get highlighted in a cyan color. When I place the cursor on the curly braces, however, no highlighting happens.

```
// cmake example
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")
   ^                  ^               ^            ^
   |                  |               |            |
   |                  +------+--------+            |
   |                         |                     |
   |                         +--- no highlighting  |
   |                                               |
   +-------------------------+---------------------+
                             |
                             +--- expected highlighting works
```

Note that the set may need to be inside a sub-block to fail (i.e inside an `if(SOMETHING) ... endif(SOMETHING)` block for example).

Here is another example with C++ code:

```
// C++ example
a = "this (string) here";   // this one fails, it's inside a string
a = string("here");         // here the highlight works
```

As we can see the parenthesis are outside of a string and the curly braces are inside the string.

I have the same problem in comments and various other types of string-like regions.

How do I get this highlighting to work in strings and comments like it was in older versions of Vim?

---

Here are a couple of screenshots. The vertical bar is the cursor placed just before the parenthesis or curly braces.

[image]

[image]

*Note 1: Yes. The highlighting works just fine with curly braces outside of a string, and also square brackets, `<,>`, etc.*

*Note 2: The `%` key works as expected, so I can find the matching character, but that's not as practical as the highlighting.*

---

So far, this has shown up in nearly all the files formats I used (C++, Go, JavaScript, Ruby, CMakeLists.txt, etc.) However, at least the parenthesis and curly braces do work fine in a shell script (`sh`).

As for the matched pairs, I have:

```
matchpairs=(:),{:},[:],<:>
```

I added the `<:>` in my settings, but the problem occurred before I added those and whether I specify `matchit` or not:

```
set matchpairs+=<:>
packadd! matchit
```

Further, I tried to comment out all of my entries in my `~/.vimrc` and the results are the same.

---

On my clean install, I see the same issues. I tried to add

```
matchadd! matchit
let b:match_skip = "0"
```

to my `~/.vimrc` and that had no effect on the issue.

Just in case, here is the `/usr/share/vim/vim80/debian.vim` file that gets loaded through the `/etc/vim/vim.vim` (I removed the full line comments to make it shorter):

```
set runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim80,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
set nocompatible    " Use Vim defaults instead of 100% vi compatibility
set backspace=indent,eol,start  " more powerful backspacing
set history=50      " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler       " show the cursor position all the time
set nomodeline
set suffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg,.inx,.out,.toc
if &term =~ "xterm-debian" || &term =~ "xterm-xfree86"
  set t_Co=16
  set t_Sf=[3%dm
  set t_Sb=[4%dm
endif
if has("autocmd")
  if has('gui')
    function! <SID>MapExists(name, modes)
      for mode in split(a:modes, '\zs')
        if !empty(maparg(a:name, mode))
          return 1
        endif
      endfor
      return 0
    endfunction
    autocmd GUIEnter * if !<SID>MapExists("<S-Insert>", "nvso") | execute "map <S-Insert> <MiddleMouse>" | endif
    autocmd GUIEnter * if !<SID>MapExists("<S-Insert>", "ic") | execute "map! <S-Insert> <MiddleMouse>" | endif
  endif
endif
if filereadable("/etc/papersize")
  let s:papersize = matchstr(readfile('/etc/papersize', '', 1), '\p*')
  if strlen(s:papersize)
    exe "set printoptions+=paper:" . s:papersize
  endif
endif
```

---

See related question: [MatchIt not matching anymore if parenthesis, brackets, etc. are between quotes or in comments?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22203)

Comment: What's the filetype? Try `:set filetype?`. Do you have curly braces in matchpairs? `:set matchpairs?` (I'm thinking you do, since `%` works...)

Comment: @filbranden I added that info, but so far it has happened in all file formats I've been working with (from what I recall) My example here is a CMake file.

Comment: Vim 8 includes matchparen which is *supposed to* ignore pairs happening inside strings (it uses the syntax engine to detect that.) However, I didn't really manage to reproduce your issue on one of my setups, so not sure what happened with that... I believe there might be tweaks you can do to enable highlighting matches in strings (or, more specifically, disabling ignoring them inside strings.)

Comment: @filbranden Okay. I tried commenting out everything in my `.vimrc` file and I get the same effect. Are there other files that vim would auto-load? One side note: it works in strings of `sh` files.

Comment: @filbranden Well... I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a VPS with X-Windows and tested gvim on that. This is a pristine install and I see the exact same problems. Now looking at what gets loaded, I can see that there are many files (several under `/etc/vim` and the `/usr/share/vim/vim80/debian` file too). But if no one knows of an option to turn off the highlight when the matchit elements are inside a string, I'm wondering whether this is a _forced feature_.

Comment: Did you try adding both `packadd! matchit` **and** `let b:match_skip = "0"` in your vimrc? Give me some more time on this one... This question *is* super interesting, but unfortunately I haven't managed to get enough time on a machine where I can mess up with Vim enough to reproduce and fix this. (Also, for some reason, my setups don't reproduce this and I want to dig into *why* that is...)

Comment: @filbranden I tried those two and it made no different, either directly or in my `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: so if I understand it correctly, it's not `matchit` that is not working but `matchparen`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a little investigation. At first I could not reproduce, but I think I have found the problem (part of it was, you did not mention what version you were using :/)

I have a local machine with an Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS installed. In it, I could reproduce the problem when using the system vim (I usually compile my own), that is version *8.0.1453*.

I traced the problem to the matchparen plugin. The matchparen plugin tries to find a matching parenthesis to the one where the cursor is while skipping special syntax groups like `string` or `comment`, *if the cursor is not also in such a group*. If the cursor is in such a group, it will not skip any match, by setting the special `s_skip` variable to `0`.

Now, there was a patch [8.0.1239](http://github.com/vim/vim/commit/48570488f17e397183ea7), that allows to use partials, funcrefs and strings as skip-expressions. At the same time, using a number as a skip expression would not work anymore and would silently return **no-match**. So that unfortunately regressed the default matchparen plugin, that comes with vim. (I think later on, *searchpair* and related functions did actually throw an error in that case.)

This problem was noticed and finally fixed by patch [v8.1.0115](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/b7a5ab112ab2267c54acdb6a326642afcd797bc4) which makes sure, that the matchparen plugin uses a *string* for the skip expression.

**What to do?**

In your case, copy the plugin that comes from the distribution to your local runtime directory (create the ~/.vim/plugin folder if it does not exist yet):

```
cp /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim ~/.vim/plugin
```

Now edit that file and apply this patch:

```
diff --git a/runtime/plugin/matchparen.vim b/runtime/plugin/matchparen.vim
index 4f68fd87b..0fa5c4d22 100644
--- a/runtime/plugin/matchparen.vim
+++ b/runtime/plugin/matchparen.vim
@@ -114,7 +114,7 @@ function! s:Highlight_Matching_Pair()
   " within those syntax types (i.e., not skip).  Otherwise, the cursor is
   " outside of the syntax types and s_skip should keep its value so we skip any
   " matching pair inside the syntax types.
-  execute 'if' s_skip '| let s_skip = 0 | endif'
+  execute 'if' s_skip '| let s_skip = "0" | endif'

   " Limit the search to lines visible in the window.
   let stoplinebottom = line('w$')
```

e.g. change line 117 and from `... = 0` to `... = "0"` (notice the double quotes).

Then restart Vim and it should work again.

(An alternative would be to install a Vim newer than 8.1.0115, which comes with updated runtime files.

Comment: I just have to wonder... why is that execute even necessary??

Comment: @D.BenKnoble you need to evaluate the skip expression, e.g. you need to know, whether to skip those special syntax groups or not. That's why you are `executing` it.

Comment: Ah wait yes I see; it is a string that represents an expression. /facepalm